# How to call database package in ODI? The db package contains list of functions and out of those I want to call only one function in ODI

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

There's a database package and it contains list of functions. Out of the list, I want to call one function in ODI12c. I tried to create an ODI procedure and within that called the db package using .(return variable); 
However, when I execute this ODI procedure, it fails with error saying " is not a procedure or is undefined.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

I tried to create an ODI procedure and within that called the db package using .(return variable);

Error:  is not a procedure or is undefined.

Comment: To call the DB package in ODI, created an ODI procedure and called the db package as <pakcageName>.<FunctionName>()

Comment: You would need to at least put it in a PL/SQL block with a `BEGIN` and `END;`. See my answer below for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a call to function, there has to be a variable created in ODI procedure to which the function returns the value.
So I did a small change and it worked.

```
DECLARE 
var1 varchar2(1000);
v_ret Boolean;
BEGIN
     v_ret := <Function Call>;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to store the value returned by that function into a ODI variable, you can use something like this as the refresh query for that variable :

```
select <SCHEMA_NAME>.<PACKAGE_NAME>.<FUNCTION_NAME>(<PARAMETERS>) from DUAL;
```

You can then refresh that variable in a package or a load plan.

If you don't need to store the result of the function but just execute it, the easiest is to use a PL/SQL block in your ODI Procedure. So make sure you set the technology to Oracle for that procedure step. Then use something like this :

```
BEGIN
    <SCHEMA_NAME>.<PACKAGE_NAME>.<FUNCTION_NAME>(<PARAMETERS>);
END;
```

A nicer way to do it would be to avoid hardcoding the schema name and get it from the topology instead. As it can be a different schema through different contexts we need to use the [substitution API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.3/odikd/substitution-api-reference.html#GUID-B7030FF7-9B09-4DAC-8B8C-B824DC47463C) that will replace it at runtime. Here would be the result for a variable :

```
select <%=odiRef.getSchemaName("<LOGICAL_SCHEMA_NAME>", "D")%>.<PACKAGE_NAME>.<FUNCTION_NAME>(<PARAMETERS>) from DUAL;
```

And for a procedure :

```
BEGIN
    <%=odiRef.getSchemaName("<LOGICAL_SCHEMA_NAME>", "D")%>.<PACKAGE_NAME>.<FUNCTION_NAME>(<PARAMETERS>);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you Jerome. I will try this today and will post my outcome.